# Quick create form doesn't show for task, appointment entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

I don't see task, appointment entities are not in the list of quick create form when click on (+) button though quick create form enabled from entity definition even quick create forms also available on forms section for those entities.

I only see other entities like account, opportunity etc. on the list through (+) button.

Comment: Where are you checking? UCI app? Screenshot pls. They will be under activities.

Comment: Yes just a week back I wished to quick create activities but it was anyway opening normal form. I believe quick create does not work w.r.t activities.

Answer (score 1):

You have to look for the below option:

[image]

Last time when I check, web always opens Main form when Quick create is expected to open (Ankuser confirmed this). But UCI opens QC forms when attempted from Timeline & Top bar.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I have resolved my problem. It seems that I needed to enable task, appointment entities from powerapps.

Comment: Oh yeah, assets & artifacts has to be added in UCI apps :)